# null dereference in React 15.1 on image load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into a strange error after updating to react 15.1 from react 0.14:

> ReactDOMComponentTree.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$wzdyscjjtuxtcehaa6ep6tj4i' of null

It appears that a "load" event from  an image buried in the page using a data url is causing an event and react walks up the DOM and when it hits the top element react injected it has no parentElement and then tries to access a member on the "null" parentElement

Simplified application (abridged):

```
class App extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return <div id="rootcomponent">
      ...
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="rootcomponent">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The element with id "rootelement" has a null parentElement which causes the error. The page otherwise seems to work which is perplexing to me.

Stacktrace:

```
getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:105)
findParent (ReactEventListener.js:39)
handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:68)
Mixin.perform (Transaction.js:136)
ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBat…Strategy.js:63)
batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:98)
ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:150)
```

Thoughts on correcting this? Maybe a react bug?

Comment: I think you need to show more code... what you have in your example works just fine in React 15

Comment: I'll see about making a unit case. In my debugging it seems to specifically be related to image load events.

Comment: Can you show how you're loading the image in your code then? It's in your top level component's render method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a Derp.

I just noticed that my javascript was getting loaded twice. I had also updated the HtmlWebpackPlugin across a major version and it changed some behaviour involving injecting the javascript. So it was in my template and the plugin was also injecting it.

After removing the line from the template so the JavaScript is loaded once, everything is fine.

That's what I get for updating libraries at 5pm.

Comment: Please close this issue, as it's not reproducible or answerable here on SO.

Comment: Please share your configuration, to fix that issue.

Comment: I removed the line from the template, i updated my answer to reflect that. You can also set the "inject" option on the plugin to false if you want to use the one in your template.

Comment: @Thomas Awesome! Had not noticed but mine was as well!! :S

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for shedding light on your solutions. That's exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it only typo problem? **Lack of parenthesis** around retuned JSX content.

```
class App extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return (<div id="rootcomponent">
      ...
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is ( ) are optional in this case. Just to be sure, I just tried it and there was no effect.

Comment: They are indeed optional the way you have written them, as well as the semi colon after your closing div ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas He is correct. In my case, I manually populate  **vendor.js** in `index.html` and in the meantime, I configure webpack to use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to inject emitted  **vendor.js** as well.

Obviously, it loads **vendor.js** twice and throws out the same error.